# Walkthrough plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is there a plugin for jQuery that would replicate the functionality exhibited on Yahoo's Finance site? http://finance.yahoo.com/

(The yellow pop up, then the highlighted sections on the page...)

I've been scouring Google and haven't come up with anything similar yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look like Yahoo! Finance has this feature anymore... I've since switched over to [Embedded Help](http://embedded-help.net/home), which is roughly what I was after.

Comment: This is a cool jQuery plugin that does something similar: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Answer (score 1):

An excellent solution was posted on a linked question: [Website Tour with jQuery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/)